# Вывод свойства "Привязка к элементам" в порядке заполнения . Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, сортировка, фильтрация

Возникла сложность с выполнением следующей задачи. Есть шаблон детальной новостной статьи, для статьи в инфоблоке задано свойство "Привязка к элементам". В этом свойстве прописываются другие статьи, которые будут выводится списком под текстом.
Проблема в том, что нужно выводить эти статьи в том порядке, в котором они задаются в админке при заполнении свойства "Привязка к элементам", но стандартные варианты сортировки такого не дают, а если сортировку отключить совсем, то статьи выводятся по разделам (сначала статьи раздела 1, потом статьи раздела 2 и т.д.).
Как это можно реализовать?

Фильтр задается стандартно

```
<?
   global  $filterNews;
   $filterNews = array("ID"=>$arResult['PROPERTIES']['ADD_NEWS']['VALUE']);

?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:news.detail", 
array(
...
"FILTER_NAME" => "filterNews",
...
?>
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь историю версий модуля инфоблоков - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/docs/versions.php?module=iblock - версия 18.6.700. Предпоследний пункт. Я этого не пробовал, не знаю как это будет работать в компоненте новостей, нужно пробовать.

Comment: И вот еще пост - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/17890/blog/35773/